# C++ how to get folders and files names from virtual device?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, explorer, readdir

How to get all folders and files names in virtual device plugged to pc?
In C++;

I have problem because the virtual device not have a letter like local disc;
Path started like this "Computer\SUPRA_M727G\Internal storage"
[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We have no idea what the device is, or how it is mounted, or what its driver does. All we know is that it is called "COMPUTER" in Windows Explorer's graphical path representation.

Comment: This device is internal storage of Android tabled, which mounted via MTP protocol.
I can't get files from this device because i know only how to read files from logical drives which have a letter.

Comment: Local disks (or volumes, really) do not have drive letters. Drive letters are a remnant of the past, from a time long before you were even born. Instead, volumes are referenced by name throughout the system. Volume names have the syntax: \\?\Volume{GUID}\. See [Naming a Volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365248.aspx) for additional information. Drive letters are nothing but a convenience, and a compatibility burden.

Comment: Start from this http://rsdn.ru/article/winshell/winshell.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Shell interfaces, namely [`IShellFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075.aspx) and [`IEnumIDList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761982.aspx).

To get an `IShellFolder` for the `"Internal storage"` folder, you can either:

1. Use [`SHGetDesktopFolder()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175.aspx) to get an `IShellFolder` for the root of the Shell namespace, then pass the `"Computer\SUPRA_M727G\Internal storage"` string to its [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775090.aspx) method to get an absolute [`ITEMIDLIST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321.aspx) that you can pass to its [`IShellFolder::BindToObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775059.aspx) method.
2. Use [`SHParseDisplayName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236.aspx) or [`ILCreateFromPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378420.aspx) to convert the `"Computer\SUPRA_M727G\Internal storage"` string into an absolute [`ITEMIDLIST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321.aspx) that you can pass to [`SHBindToObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762113.aspx) with its `psf` parameter set to `NULL`.

Either way, once you have an `IShellFolder` for the storage folder, you can use its [`IShellFolder::EnumObjects()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775066.aspx) method to get an `IEnumIDList` for enumerating its files and subfolders.  The enumeration will give you a relative `ITEMIDLIST` for each item.  To retrieve each item's name as a string, pass each `ITEMIDLIST` to its [`IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775071.aspx) method, and then pass the returned [`STRRET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759820.aspx) to one of the `StrRetTo...()` functions ([`StrRetToBSTR()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773423.aspx), [`StrRetToBuf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773426.aspx), or [`StrRetToStr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773430.aspx)).

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Introduction to the Shell Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090.aspx)

[Navigating the Shell Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521706.aspx)